Is there a way to convert letters to numbers in python
I have a data frame below that corresponds letters to numbers.
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3], ['D', 4], ['E', 5], ['F', 6]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Letters', 'Num'])

Now keeping this, can we convert a sentence containing these letters to numbers and then taking a sum of it
Example
I have a sentence like
sen = 'Ab df ec'

Now these corresponds to 12 46 53. There it is 1+2+0+4+6+0+5+3 = 21 (0 is for space). Therefore the sentence Ab df ec will make a sum of 21

A simple dictionary is all you need.  Pandas is not helping you here.
data = [['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3], ['D', 4], ['E', 5], ['F', 6]]
data = {a:b for a,b in data}
data[' '] = 0

sen = 'Ab df ec'
print(sum(data[i.upper()] for i in sen))

Output:
21


Could use data = dict(data).

Excellent point.  Even after all these years, I still forget about that option.

One of the fastest way would be to do the following:
from string import ascii_letters

sen = 'Ab df ec'
sen_idx = [ord(x)-64 for x in sen.upper() if x in ascii_letters]


ord(x) - each symbol in python has it's own number value. Like A - 65, Z - 90, a - 97, z - 122. Basically letters are ordered, but upper and lower case letters have their own numbers.
convert your string to upper and apply ord only to upper letters (because in your case upper case and lower case letters must have same numbers).
avoid taking ord from spaces, commas and other punctuation by checking that all letters belong to ascii_letters

Second solution:
from string import ascii_uppercase

# dict with all letters and their index
# {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, ...}
data = {letter: idx+1 for idx,letter in enumerate(ascii_uppercase)}

sen = 'Ab df ec'

# for non letters use 0
sen_idx = [data.get(x, 0) for x in sen.upper() ]

print(sen_idx) # [1, 2, 0, 4, 6, 0, 5, 3]


Better start enumerating with 1.
